# changing time format with preg replace in php

Tags: php, regex, replace, pcre

i m just wondering if we can do this with preg replace

like if there's time like

```
1h 38 min
```

can change to

```
98 mins
```

---

```
2h 20 min
```

can change to

```
140 mins
```

or just suggest me any other random function to this is simpler way

thanks

Comment: How are you receiving the formats, `138` or `1h 38min`?

Comment: sometimes it comes like 1h 38 min and sometimes its like 2h 20 min, thing is like 1 hours or 2 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str="1h 38 min";
$s = explode(" ",$str);
if ( strpos ( $s[0] ,"h" ) !==FALSE) {
    $hr=str_replace("h","",$s[0]);
    print ($hr*60) + $s[1]."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This simple function should do the trick. It does no verification on the string format, though.

```
function reformat_time_string($timestr) {
    $vals = sscanf($timestr, "%dh %dm");
    $total_min = ($vals[0] * 60) + $vals[1];
    return "$total_min mins";
}

$timestr = "2h 15m";
echo reformat_time_string($timestr); /* echoes '135 mins' */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = '!(\d+)\s*h\s*(\d+)\s*min!';
foreach( array('1h 38 min', '2h 20 min') as $input) {
  echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($x) { return ($x[1]*60+$x[2]).' minutes'; }, $input), "\n";
}
```

prints

```
98 minutes
140 minutes
```

for php versions prior to 5.3 you'd have to use

```
function foo($x) {
  return ($x[1]*60+$x[2]).' minutes';
}
$pattern = '!(\d+)\s*h\s*(\d+)\s*min!';
foreach( array('1h 38 min', '2h 20 min') as $input) {
  echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'foo', $input), "\n";
}
```

Comment: preg replace gives error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION